# Filtering in Linq with where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the users based on the continent for my application. I used the following code for this. Now I want to show all users if the continentId is null. How can I achieve this?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersByContinent(int? continentId)
{
     var users = await _context.Users
            .Include(u => u.Country).ThenInclude(c => c.Continent)
            .Where(u => u.Country.ContinentId == continentId)
            .OrderBy(u => u.Username)
            .ToListAsync();

    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use method chaining to solve your problem.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersByContinent(int? continentId)
{
     var baseQuery= _context.Users.Include(u => u.Country).ThenInclude(c => c.Continent);

     if (continentId.HasValue){
         baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(u => u.Country.ContinentId == continentId)
     }

     return await baseQuery.OrderBy(u => u.Username).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jehof. I could achieved it according to your solution. I had to put AsQueryable() at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use @Jehof solution, but it's worth mentioning alternative solution.

```
.Where(u => continentId == null || u.Country.ContinentId == continentId)
```

Comment: Thanks Orel. Here if the continentId is null, then it returns nothing. But I want to return all the users if the continentId is null.